# Modify multiple columns of dataset by the same function in R

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe, apply

Here is a code to generate a data.frame :

```
ref_variables=LETTERS[1:10]
row=100
d0=seq(1:100)
for (i in seq_along(ref_variables)){
  dtemp=sample(seq(1:row),row,TRUE)
  d0=data.frame(d0,dtemp)
}
d0[,1]=NULL
names(d0)=ref_variables
```

I have a dataset, data.frame or data.table, whatever.
Let's say I want to modify the columns 2 to 4 by dividing each of them by the first one. Of Course, I can make a loop like this :

```
columns_name_to_divide=c("B","C","H")
column_divisor="A"
for (i in seq_along(columns_name_to_divide)){        
  ds[columns_name_to_divide[i]] = ds[columns_name_to_divide[i]] / ds[column_divisor]
}
```

But is there a way more elegant to do it?

Answer (score 4):

```
  > d0[2:4] <- d0[,2:4]/d0[,1]
```

This will substitute your original values with result you get after dividing column 2,3,4 by column 1. Rest will remain the same.

If you want to create 3 new columns in `d0` with new values after dividing column 2,3,4 by column 1 This will not replace the original values in column 2,3, and 4. The calculated values would be in column 11,12 and 13 respectively.

```
  > dim(d0)
  # [1] 100  10
  > d0[11:13] <- d0[,2:4]/d0[,1]
  > dim(d0)
  # [1] 100  13
```

To round up the new values, you can simply add `round()` function to 2 decimal places like below:

```
  > d0[2:4] <- round(d0[,2:4]/d0[,1],2)  # Original values subtituted at 2,3,4

  # OR

  > d0[11:13] <- round(d0[,2:4]/d0[,1],2)  # New columns added, original columns are untouched.
```

Comment: Don't think this one works, generates error: ‘/’ only defined for equally-sized data frames. Example: d[,c(25, 26)] <-d[,c(25, 26)] / d[,24]

Answer (score 2):

We can use `set` from `data.table` which would be make this more efficient as the overhead of `.[data.table` is avoided when called multiple times (though not in this case).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d0)
for(j in columns_name_to_divide){
   set(d0, i = NULL, j = j, value = d0[[j]]/d0[[column_divisor]])
}
```

---

Or using `lapply`

```
setDT(d0)[, (columns_name_to_divide) := lapply(.SD, `/`, 
              d0[[column_divisor]]), .SDcols = columns_name_to_divide]
```

---

Or an elegant option using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
d0 %<>%
    mutate_each_(funs(./d0[[column_divisor]]), columns_name_to_divide)
head(d0)
#  A         B         C  D  E  F  G        H  I  J
#1 60 0.4000000 1.1500000  6 86 27 19 0.150000 94 97
#2 11 0.6363636 0.3636364 25 52 44 82 8.818182 84 68
#3 80 0.8750000 1.1375000 72 34 56 69 0.125000 34 17
#4 77 0.3116883 1.0259740  9 44 87 61 1.064935 79 40
#5 18 0.3333333 5.0555556 60 69 62 89 2.166667 21 34
#6 42 1.3333333 2.3095238 61 20 87 95 1.428571 78 63
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(42)
d1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, 1e7*7, replace=TRUE), ncol=7))

d2 <- copy(d1)
d3 <- copy(d1)

system.time({
d2 %<>%
   mutate_each(funs(./d2[["V2"]]), V4:V7)
})
# user  system elapsed 
#   0.52    0.39    0.91 

system.time({
d1[,4:7] <- d1[,4:7]/d1[,2]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.72    0.72    2.44 


system.time({

setDT(d3)
for(j in 4:7){
   set(d3, i = NULL, j = j, value = d3[[j]]/d3[["V2"]])
}

})
#  user  system elapsed 
#   0.32    0.16    0.47
```

Comment: `[.data.table` overhead (usually) comes into play when called multiple times. It'd be called just once here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
library(data.table)


cols <- names(df)[2:4]
col1 <- names(df)[1]

setDT(df)[, (cols) := lapply (cols, function(x)  get(x) / get(col1) )]


# sample data for reproducible example:
df <- data.frame(V1=rep(10,5),
                 V2=rep(20,5),
                 V3=rep(30,5),
                 V4=rep(40,5),
                 V5=rep(50,5))
```

Comment: From next version on you can do: `setDT(df)[, (cols) := lapply (.SD, function(x)  x * V1), .SDcols=cols]`. [It has been fixed recently](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/495).